# paracol breaks title marks in headers set by titleps

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, bugs, paracol, titleps

I noticed that the `paracol` environment from the paracol package makes `\toptitlemarks`, `\firsttitlemarks`, and `\bottitlemarks` from the titleps package not work. See the following code:

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titleps, paracol, lipsum}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\newpagestyle{main}{
    \sethead{\toptitlemarks Top is \thesection}
        {\firsttitlemarks First is \thesection}
        {\bottitlemarks Bot is \thesection}
}
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Second}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

The result of the header is:

```
Top is 2    First is 2  Bot is 2
```

But the expected result is:

```
Top is 1    First is 1  Bot is 2
```

If you comment out the `paracol` lines, you will get the expected result:

```tex
%\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[1]
%\switchcolumn
\lipsum[1]
%\end{paracol}
```

Why is `paracol` causing this bug? I tried the same thing but with parcolumns instead of paracol, and it worked fine. But I don't want to use parcolumns because it has other issues. Is there a way to fix this with paracol, and if not, is there a better alternative to paracol?

Comment: This doesn't surprise me. `paracol` makes extensive changes to the output routine, and that's where the marks should be set. As far as I could see, it doesn't do this properly.

Comment: Why does paracol do that? parcolumns doesn't have this issue but my problem with parcolumns is that it tries to make the lines align, making English on one column have huge spaces between lines to adjust for the diacratics of Arabic text on another column. It's bad for multilingual typesetting.

Comment: The algorithm in `paracol` is quite compilcated to get the parts aligned.

Comment: Are there advantages of it being this complicated? Is there any other LaTeX package (aside from parcolumns and parallel) that works like paracol but doesn't have this issue? I checked the [parallel](https://ctan.org/topic/parallel) topic on CTAN and I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: It is complicated, because the columns can be arbitrarily long, maybe several pages. So breaking these into pages requires saving the excess of each column (the parts that don't fit on the current page) and then use these on the next pages(s). The presence of footnotes makes it even more complicated.

Comment: For the next version of my package `extramarks`, which is not yet released but in beta version, I have coded several patches for `paracol` to get the marks right. I guess `titleps` should do something similar, or `paracol` should offer some API for this to solve it.

Comment: Does that mean that the beta version of your package extramarks solves this issue? To use it, do I need to use fancyhdr instead of titleps, or can I still use it with titleps? Can I install your patched version of paracol to get the correct title marks with titleps without using extramarks?  Finally, where can I download the beta version of extramarks? Sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: See the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amarakon My package `extramarks` uses a different definition of `topmark` than `titleps`. It uses the original TeX definition "the last mark of the previous page", which in your example would be empty. However `titleps` uses either the first mark of the page if there is no text before it, or the last mark from the previous page if there is one, otherwise the first mark on the page, if I understand it correctly.

There is no easy way to get the same result with `extramarks`. And no, `extramarks` doesn't solve the problem for `titleps`. By the way, there is no "patched version of `paracol`", the patches are applied dynamically while loading `extramarks`.

And if you want to try it, you can find it at https://github.com/pietvo/fancyhdr/tree/5.0beta

Here is a solution with that approximates your problem, but the solution differs in the handling of topmarks.

```
\documentclass{book}

% !!!! Needs package `extramarks' version 5.0 or 5.0beta.
\usepackage{fancyhdr, extramarks, paracol, lipsum}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

% This approximates the `titleps' `topmark`, but it is not the same.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \tl_toporfirst
\newcommand{\toporfirstxmark}{%
  \tl_set:Nx \tl_toporfirst \topleftxmark
  \tl_if_empty:VTF \tl_toporfirst {\firstleftxmark} {\topleftxmark}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\extramarks{\thesection}{#1}}
\fancypagestyle{main}{
  \fancyhead[L]{Top is \toporfirstxmark}
  \fancyhead[C]{First is \firstleftxmark}
  \fancyhead[R]{Bot is \lastleftxmark}
}
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Second}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Also, how do I get the corresponding section title for each part of the header? `\rightmark` didn't work for me.

Comment: That would be `\firstrightxmark`,  or `\lastrightxmark` (note the `x`).

Comment: Thanks, I created `\toporfirstrightxmark` in the same way that you created `\toporfirstxmark`.